# How to get all the latitude and longitude points using a central lat, long point with a radius of 1 km?

Tags: python, location, coordinates, latitude-longitude, area

I have a central lat, long point along with radius of 1 km. I want to fetch all the lat, long points inside 1 km.

From the output list, I want to compare values with another lat, long value to check whether it is matching or not?

For example, If I have a point that is (51.42337159689999, -0.562302811958012). I want to fetch all the points in 1 km radius.

Which is the better way to do this? Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 6):

Here's my rough attempt... Hopefully this helps getting your brain flowing?

```
import math

def findpoints(lon, lat):
    radius = 1
    N = 360 

    # generate points
    circlePoints = []
    for k in range(N):
        angle = math.pi*2*k/N
        dx = radius*math.cos(angle)
        dy = radius*math.sin(angle)
        point = {}
        point['lat']= lat + (180/math.pi)*(dy/6371) #Earth Radius
        point['lon']= lon + (180/math.pi)*(dx/6371)/math.cos(lon*math.pi/180) #Earth Radius
        # add to list
        circlePoints.append(point)

    return circlePoints
```